# HOW TO: display a check mark, disable a menu item, refresh a menubar

Tags: cocoa, menu, applescript, nsmenuitem, applescript-objc

I am trying to set up some simple services on a Mac using a menubar/status script with applescript.
After having read the web up and down, bearing in mind I am new to scripting, it seems I have reached my limit and I need some help...

First, I want to display a check mark next to a menuItem on a condition. In my example the condition is the display resolution between 720p and 1080p.

I have set up the menubar adapted from an existing script (some of which I do not fully understand) as follows:

```
use AppleScript version "2.7"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"

property aStatusItem : missing value

on init()
        set aBar to {"Reset Display", "1080p", "720p", "Open Monitor Preferences...", "", "External Monitor: active", "Quit"}
        set aStatusItem to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s statusItemWithLength:(current application's NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        aStatusItem's setTitle:"FTV"
        aStatusItem's setHighlightMode:true
        aStatusItem's setMenu:(createMenu(aBar) of me)

    end init

    on createMenu(aList)
        set myDisplay to ChkDisplay()
        set aMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
        set aCount to 1
        repeat with i in aList
            set j to contents of i
            if j is not equal to "" then
                set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:j action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"")
            else

                set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's separatorItem())
            end if
            if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:NSOnState)
            (aMenuItem's setTarget:me)
            (aMenuItem's setTag:aCount)
            (aMenu's addItem:aMenuItem)
            if j is not equal to "" then set aCount to aCount + 1
        end repeat
        return aMenu
    end createMenu
```

The handler to check the display resolution:

```
    on ChkDisplay()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        set myDisplay to "720p"
        tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "Philips FTV" of process "System Preferences"
            if selected of row 1 then set myDisplay to "1080p"
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    return myDisplay
end ChkDisplay
```

Basically I want the check mark to move from 720p to 1080p depending on which of the resolution is active. The 720p and 1080p item, if clicked, will also set the display resolution.

The code I have return an error: NSOnState is not defined... and there I am lost.

The second issue I have is to find a way to:
a) "grey out" (disable) a menuItem (in this case, the item "External Monitor: active"
b) to have the item change to "External Monitor: missing" on a condition

I have tried: NSMenuItem highlight:false and NSMenuItem enabled:false and both returned and error. 
In addition, I don't know how to refresh the menu and/or a menu item.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.
I thank anyone in advance for the time (s)he will spend on my thinking about those questions!

Comment: Do not cross post the same question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320172/how-to-display-check-mark-next-to-menu-item-and-disable-menu-item on multiple SE sites!

Comment: I can solve your first problem for you: `NSOnState` ought to be `(current application's NSOnState)`.  Also, read [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514863-enabled?language=objc) of the developer documentation in Obj-C relating to `NSMenuItem's enabled` property.  Specifically: **This property has no effect unless the menu in which the item will be added or is already a part of has been sent `setAutoenablesItems:NO`.**  The developer documentation is really good, I feel.

Comment: Can you tell me what's actually going on here ? The question is quite confusing, and having read it through a few times, I still am not clear whether you're creating your own application, or attempting to control another, or what the script is supposed to be doing (OK, I roughly know, having read it, but there's next to know context here, so I don't know what you're doing).  Also, the `ChkDisplay` handler is going to be very difficult for anyone to test on their system, as they probably have different display options.  720p/1800p isn't even listed on mine...

Comment: @CJK, thanks a lot for your help. After carefully reading again `if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:(current application's NSOnState))` does put un check mark next to the desired menu item! To reply to your second comment, I am making my own application to toggle the external monitor connected to a Mac mini: therefore you are right when you say the ChkDisplay handler is very specific. I would like to disable one item of the menu as it is only meant to display an information, but not be clickable and finally refresh my menubar when a change in display occurs (resolution or otherwise)

Comment: I did and it works even smoother than `(current application's NSOnState)` so that bit of code is simply `if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:1)`. I am now working on the enable/disable bit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Solution

**For issue #1, displaying a check mark next to a menu item**, thanks to @CJK help, I have found some working code:

replace `if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:NSOnState)` by either

```
if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:1)
```

or

```
if j = myDisplay then (aMenuItem's setState:NSOnState)
```

I have also been able to display any image next to a menu item with NSimage (do not hesitate to ask me if need be)

**As regards issue #2, enabling/disabling a menu item**, I also have found a working code:

in the createMenu(aList) handler, you need to add the second line before the repeat loop:

```
set aMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
aMenu's setAutoenablesItems:false
```

then in the repeat loop, to enable/disable a menu item:

```
(aMenuItem's setEnabled:false)
```

**Finally to refresh the menu items, ** I put the code `aMenu's removeAllItems()` in createMenu(aList) handler and call the handler when I want to refresh. It seems by removing on run/ end run at the beginning of the script, everything works fine!